# jQuery save/edit button action only when button has a specific ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I have an HTML table(Dynamic) and a save/edit button on each row. On clicking save, the values needs to be collected to jQuery variables and AJAX POSTed to a PHP page. I am able to retrieve the values in 3 Table cells, but being a CSS counter, I am not able to get the value of the Sl:No column. It is important that I get this number.

## HTML TABLE

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td contenteditable="false" class="sorting_1"><span class="sl"> </span> </td>
    <td contenteditable="false"> <span class="name">Alex Nilson </span></td>
    <td contenteditable="false"><span class="price"> 1234 </span></td>
    <td contenteditable="false"> <span class="qty">1234 </span></td>
    <td><button class="pr_edit" href="javascript:;"> Edit </button></td>
    <td><button class="pr_elete" href="javascript:;"> Delete </button></td>

</tr>
```

The jQuery function is as follows.

```
$('#sample_editable_1').on('click', '.pr_edit', function() {
    var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');


    var ino = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.sl").text();
    var iname = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.name").text();
    var iprice = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.price").text();
    var iqty = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.qty").text();

});
```

Following is the CSS code.  *#sample_editable_1*  is the name of the table.

```
  #sample_editable_1 tbody {
  counter-reset: tablerow;
}
#sample_editable_1 .sorting_1::before {
  counter-increment: tablerow;
  content: counter(tablerow)". ";

}
```

It all works perfectly except the following trouble.

1. The sl span is a CSS counter. I am not being able to retrieve the value of this SPAN.

Comment: Please add a screen shot of css counter. and you can only get text by `jquery` when count is in between `<span>1</span>` .

Comment: can you show us the css counter increment?? (code)

Comment: Instead of closest('tr') ...u try go forward from td `var ino = currentTD.find('span.sl').text(); console.log(ino);`

Comment: I think you should research on `CSSPrimitiveValue.getCounterValue()` ...

Comment: Code updated. @narasimharaosp

Comment: I did some testing in jsfiddle. First, the variable "sl" is never defined in your script, so you'd get an error. Try console.log(ino);

Comment: Secondly, check if your HTML code is valid. It appears that .closest('tr') will fail if <tr> is not inside a <table>. Otherwise, there's no problem with your code.

Comment: @daniel: sl is the name of the SPAN class

Comment: but sl is not a variable in your script. You need something like `var sl = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.sl")`

Comment: var ino = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.sl").text(); @daniel
I dont need a sl in the script. sl is the name of the span

Answer (score 0):

Not possible yet in my opinion.

First, the sad truth is that, you might not be able to get the value at all, currently, as `:before`/`:after` psuedo-elements are not part of the DOM and accessing them and going in this route is messy one.

You should check these links out, so that you can understand what I mean:

[How can I read the applied CSS-counter value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532073/how-can-i-read-the-applied-css-counter-value)

[How to access CSS generated content with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript)

Second thing is that there is the `CSSPrimitiveValue.getCounterValue()` which fairly new to the Javascript and does not have much support yet. You might want to research on that, if you want to proceed in that direction.

Third, I think its best if you go via a javascript approach where you generate the counter values just like the rest of the fields.

Hope it helps.

**Update**:

Based on the comments, if you want the javascript functionality, you can do something like this: (`.pr_add` is a button which adds the row)

```
$(".pr_add").on("click",function(){
  var i = 1;
  $("tr.odd").each(function(){
    $(this).children().find(".sl").html(i);
    i++;
  });
});
```

What this will do is if you click the add button, it will take all the `.sl` spans and keep the counter values.

Now if the user clicks the `.pr_delete` button, then i think you should change the code to something like this:

```
$('#sample_editable_1').on('click', 'button', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass(".pr_edit")){
      var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
      var ino = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.sl").text();
      var iname = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.name").text();
      var iprice = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.price").text();
      var iqty = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.qty").text();
    }else if($(this).hasClass(".pr_delete")){
      $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // remove the tr
      var i = 1;
      $("tr.odd").each(function(){
        $(this).children().find(".sl").html(i);
        i++;
      });
    }
});
```

I havent tested this, but check it ... and hope it gives you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: When I generate using JS, I would need to create the script that would handle the rearrangement of rows when a row is created or deleted. CSS counters does that automatically. Would you help me in developing a script that would handle row rearrangement in case row is deleted?

Comment: Can you provide us the function related to the "add row"? If possible kindly make it as a jsfiddle...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$("#dvTable").hide();
        $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {
            var iCounter = $('#sample_editable_1 tbody tr').length + 1;



            szTr = '<tr role="row" class="odd">';
            szTr = szTr + '<td contenteditable="false" class="sorting_1"><span class="sl">' + iCounter + '</span> </td>';
            szTr = szTr + '<td contenteditable="false"> <span class="name">Alex Nilson </span></td>';
            szTr = szTr + '<td contenteditable="false"><span class="price"> 1234 </span></td>';
            szTr = szTr + '<td contenteditable="false"> <span class="qty">1234 </span></td>';
            szTr = szTr + '<td><button class="pr_edit" href="javascript:;"> Edit </button></td>';
            szTr = szTr + '<td><button class="pr_elete" href="javascript:;"> Delete </button></td>';
            szTr = szTr + '</tr>';



            $('#sample_editable_1 tbody').append(szTr);

        });

        $('#sample_editable_1').on('click', '.pr_edit', function () {
            var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');


            var ino = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.sl").text();
            var iname = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.name").text();
            var iprice = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.price").text();
            var iqty = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.qty").text();

            alert(ino)

        });

    });



</script>
</head>
<body>





    Name:<input type="text" id="ename" value="Name"/><br />
    Id: <input type="text" id="eid" value="new_id"/><br />
    Des <input type="text" id="desc" value="description"/><br />
     <input type="button" value="Generate" id="btnGenerate">

    <div id="dvTable">
    <table id="sample_editable_1">
        <tbody></tbody>


    </table>


    </div>



    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</body>
</html>
```