# Reference a listed item by its counter-value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given an orderered list

```
<ol>
    <li id="item">ipsum</li>
    <li id="other">lorem</li>
<ol>
<span>The item <cite src="other?"></cite> is an item.</span>
```

Is it possible to reference the listed items by their ordinal value? e.g. if I write `<cite src="other"><cite>`, it would appear as `Item (2)`? I cannot know it's position in the list beforehand, so it would need to be done automatically in some way; is this possible in css?

Expected output:

1. ipsum
2. lorem

The item 2. is an item.

Essentially the `<cite src="other"><cite>` should copy the content of the ordinal value.

If such solution cannot be attained with the current limitations of CSS, a JavaScript solution would suffice.

Comment: Would `:nth-of-type` do?

Comment: @wscourge So if I wrote `other:nth-of-type`, would that appear as, in my example, `2`?

Comment: I think javascript is the way to go

Comment: Well, `nth-of-type` is not the way to go. Sorry for confusing you. What is your expected result? What exactly do you want to see between `<cite src="other"></cite>` tags after page is rendered? And what, if any, functionality do you want it to have?

Comment: @wscourge I added expected render; essentially it should copy the content of the list's counter value.

Comment: I found this from '09, but I would have expected this to have changed in 8 years: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532073/how-can-i-read-the-applied-css-counter-value

Comment: Are you interested in javascript solution for it? Because I don't think there's any using CSS, while js is quite simple.

Comment: @wscourge Given the lack of a css solution, I don't that I have any other choice... I think I'll rephrase the question to allow for a js solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every `<cite>` tag, loop through `<ol>` children, and if you find one with and `id` attribute matching `<cite>`'s `src` attribute, set it's position (+1) as `<cite>`'s `innerText` :

```js
var cites     = document.getElementsByTagName("cite");
var listItems = document.getElementById("my-items").children;

for(var i = 0; i < cites.length; i++) {
    var cite = cites[i];
    var src = cite.getAttribute("src");

    for (var j = 0; j < listItems.length; j++) {
        var id = listItems[j].getAttribute("id");
        if(id === src) {
             cite.innerText = j + 1;
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ol id="my-items">
    <li id="item">ipsum</li>
    <li id="other">lorem</li>
<ol>
<span>The item <cite src="other"></cite> is an item.</span>
```

**EDIT:** More efficient solution:

```js
var listItems = document.getElementById("my-items").children;

for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++ ) {
  var id = listItems[i].getAttribute("id");
  var cite = document.querySelector("[src='" + id + "']");
  if(cite) cite.innerText = i + 1;
}
```

```html
<ol id="my-items">
    <li id="item">ipsum</li>
    <li id="other">lorem</li>
<ol>
<span>The item <cite src="other"></cite> is an item.</span>
```

Comment: While this is a sufficient solution, wouldn't it be more effective to use javascript to list the items (instead of li's value) and attach its position value to a data-attribute? This value could be read directly. Its runtime should be O(#cites+#listitems) instead of O(#cites*#listitems).

Comment: See my edit. It will work assuming uniqueness of `src` attributes.