# How to copy value of div:after to other div

Tags: jquery, css, css-counter

I have a simple list of `li` elements that I want to count using the *CS*S `counter()` *function*.

```css
body       {counter-reset: quantity}
ul li      {counter-increment: quantity}
.sum:after {content: counter(quantity)}
```

```html
<div class="mirror"></div>
<ul>
  <li>..</li>
  <li>..</li>
  <li>..</li>
  <li>..</li>
  <li>..</li>
</ul>
<div class="sum"></div>
```

The problem is that counter should be at the end of the page (inside the `.sum` - after all `li`'s it needs to count) but I need to present its value at the top of the page (inside the `.mirror` or `.mirror:after`).

I'm trying to find some *jQuery* solution but nothing works. I'm thinking that the problem is with taking value from the `:after` *pseudo-element*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the ***Flexbox*** and `order` property, which comes together with its usage, to display the *counter* above *list items* since the `.mirror` div needs to be placed after the `ul` element in the DOM:

```css
body {counter-reset: quantity}
ul li {counter-increment: quantity}

.flex-container {
  display: flex; /* assigned flex behavior to the parent wrapper so that you can take advantage of the order property / displays flex-items (children) inline by default, that's why you need to change its direction */
  flex-direction: column; /* now it stacks them vertically */
}

.flex-container > ul {
  order: 1; /* displays list items below the counter even though they are above it in the DOM / 1 because the .mirror div has the default value of 0 */
}

.mirror:after {
  content: counter(quantity);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <ul>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="mirror"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the DOM is read top-to-bottom, with the **[`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)** pesudo-elements created on the fly. The elements simply don't **exist** until they're actually written to the DOM, so a simple change to `.mirror:after` won't work as you'd expect:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: quantity;
}

ul li {
  counter-increment: quantity;
}

.mirror:after {
  content: counter(quantity);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mirror"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sum"></div>
</body>
```

However, this can be gotten around using JavaScript, and waiting until the page finishes loading before outputting the counter. You can count the elements with **[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**. I've gone with a simple `li` selector for this, but it can easily be more specific if necessary.

To insert them back to the `mirror` class, you can select it with **[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**, and access it with `[0]`. The `[0]` is needed because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, and you want the first result. Then you simply set the content with **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**, as is shown in the following:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var itemCount = items.length;

var mirror = document.getElementsByClassName('mirror')[0];
mirror.innerHTML = itemCount;
```

```html
<div class="mirror"></div>

<ul>
  <li>..</li>
  <li>..</li>
  <li>..</li>
  <li>..</li>
  <li>..</li>
</ul>

<div class="sum"></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You unfortunately [can't access this value through scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532073/how-can-i-read-the-applied-css-counter-value), nor set it to a variable accessible upper in the DOM tree...

What you can do however, is to render your `.mirror` as if it were upper in the DOM tree, thanks to the `flex-direction: column` and `order` CSS3 properties.

```css
.container {
  counter-reset: quantity;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ul li {
  counter-increment: quantity;
}
.sum:after, .mirror::after {
  content: counter(quantity);
}
/* here swap the display order */
.container > .mirror {
  order: 1;
}
.container > ul {
  order: 2;
}
.container > .sum {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sum"></div>
  <div class="mirror"></div> <!-- will be moved on top of .container with CSS -->
</div>
```